# Proof regarding the convergent series of a subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Given a null sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $a_n\in\mathbb{R}^{>0},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

I need to prove that $\forall\epsilon >0,\exists (a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$

such that $(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n_k})<\epsilon$.

So basically, I think I need to construct a (geometric?) series which consists of members of the sequence $(a_n)$ and put it in relation to some $\epsilon>0$.

However I have no clue how to construct such a series.

Or is my assumption incorrect? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough that the $k$-th term of the series, $a_{n_k}$, is less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}$. Can you ensure that? Note that $\varepsilon$ is pre-given.

Comment: Why less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ in particular?

Comment: What is the sum of those terms over all $k = 1,2,\ldots$ (it's indeed a geometric series we use as an upper bound)?

Comment: That would be the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$.

Comment: Yes, what is the sum?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the exact limit. I can only prove that this series converges.

Comment: Move the $\varepsilon$ out. What is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \ldots$?

Comment: It's a geometric series. Look it up.

Comment: Ok, so the limit is 1. So multiplying by $\epsilon$ it is $\epsilon$.

Comment: Indeed it is. So...

Comment: I see now why $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$.